# Show that the sequence $y_n = 1+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}+...+\frac{1}{n^k}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq 2$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let

$y_n = 1+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}+...+\frac{1}{n^k}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq 2$.

I need to show that this sequence is convergent.

I did $y_{n+1}-y_n$ and I got that it is bigger than $0$ so the sequence is growing and I know that $y_1 \leq y_n$ but I need to also find a number which is bigger then $y_n$ which I do not know how to do. The answers says that I need to show that the sequence is smaller than $2$ but I really do not have any idea how to do it.

Comment: To be fair this was quite hard to find.